SQLite GROUP BY into two columns
I have three Tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countable(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS count(
    countableId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    collectionId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    count INTEGER NOT NULL
);

My plan is to be able to select two collections (For example collection.id = 3 OR collection.id = 4) and get two counts per countable. This already works:
+-----------+------------+-------+
| countable | collection | count |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Example   | Col 3      | 0     |
| Example   | Col 4      | 5     |
| Test      | Col 3      | 1     |
| Test      | Col 4      | 0     |
| Foo       | Col 3      | 0     |
| Foo       | Col 4      | 0     |
| Bar       | Col 3      | 5     |
| Bar       | Col 4      | 3     |
+-----------+------------+-------+

However, I want a table where there are no duplicate coutables, something like this:
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| countable | primaryCount | secondaryCount |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| Example   | 0            | 5              |
| Test      | 1            | 0              |
| Foo       | 0            | 0              |
| Bar       | 5            | 3              |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+

I tried using grouping, which sort of works:
SELECT
countable.name AS countable,
count AS primaryCount,      <--- This is the Problem
count AS secondaryCount     <--- This is the Problem
FROM count
JOIN countable ON countable.id = count.countableId
JOIN collection ON collection.id = count.collectionId
WHERE collection.id = 3 OR collection.id = 4
GROUP BY countable.id
;

But this just returns the primatyCount both times:
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| countable | primaryCount | secondaryCount |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| Example   | 0            | 0              |
| Test      | 1            | 1              |
| Foo       | 0            | 0              |
| Bar       | 5            | 5              |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+

I also tried group_concat like this:
SELECT
countable.name AS countable,
group_concat(count)
FROM count
JOIN countable ON countable.id = count.countableId
JOIN collection ON collection.id = count.collectionId
WHERE collection.id = 3 OR collection.id = 4
GROUP BY countable.id
;

This returns:
+-----------+---------------------+
| countable | group_concat(count) |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Example   | 0,5                 |
| Test      | 1,0                 |
| Foo       | 0,0                 |
| Bar       | 5,3                 |
+-----------+---------------------+

which works, however I would have to split the values in code, which is not really ideal I guess. Is there some syntax like count[0] and count[1] or other solutions to do this cleanly in SQLite?
Sample Data
Here is some sample data:
INSERT INTO countable VALUES (1, "Example");
INSERT INTO countable VALUES (2, "Test");
INSERT INTO countable VALUES (3, "Foo");
INSERT INTO countable VALUES (4, "Bar");


INSERT INTO collection VALUES (1, "Col 1");
INSERT INTO collection VALUES (2, "Col 2");
INSERT INTO collection VALUES (3, "Col 3");
INSERT INTO collection VALUES (4, "Col 4");


INSERT INTO count VALUES (1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (1, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (1, 4, 5);

INSERT INTO count VALUES (2, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (2, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (2, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (2, 4, 0);

INSERT INTO count VALUES (3, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (3, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (3, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (3, 4, 0);

INSERT INTO count VALUES (4, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (4, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (4, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO count VALUES (4, 4, 3);


You seem to just want conditional aggregation here:
SELECT
    cnt.name AS countable,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col.id = 3 THEN c.count ELSE 0 END) AS primaryCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col.id = 4 THEN c.count ELSE 0 END) AS secondaryCount
FROM count c
INNER JOIN countable cnt
    ON cnt.id = c.countableId
INNER JOIN collection col ON col.id = c.collectionId
GROUP BY cnt.name;

The idea is to aggregate by the countable name and for each group of records keep conditional tallies of the number of records belonging to collections 3 and 4.

Thank you for the answer, but for me this just returns all 1s for some reason.

Like this (sorry about the formatting):
Example | 1 | 1 ; Test | 1 | 1 ; Foo | 1 | 1 ; Bar | 1 | 1

You should have included sample data in your question.

I updated my question with some sample data

I think my edit should fix it...you want to sum the count column across records for each collection type.
